# Code execution takes more time in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have below line of code in my angular component and it takes more than 5 minutes when record count is more than 100000.

```
this.getGlobalRecordsCol.map(value => {
        const dataCheck = this.retainPrevSelectedRecords.some(checkArr => checkArr.RecordId === value.RecordID
          && checkArr.Ctr === value.Ctr);
        value.isDisabled = false;
        value.Selected = dataCheck ? false : value.Selected;
      });
```

Is it possible to optimize this logic to minimize the execution time.

Comment: um, what is 1Lak+?

Comment: @pixelbits more than 100000 records.

Comment: its the rendering that is taking a long time.  I would look into infinite scroll angular compoonents.

Comment: @pixelbits - It would be great, if you share any example/reference link

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll, when you find out the improvement, please share your findings. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-infinite-scroll

Comment: @pixelbits I tried lazy load concept and it works fine for me.